# Visual c++ problem in compiling native windows 10 application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, exe

I'm coding a native C++ application in Vs 2019 that sould be able to run on a freshly configured windows 10 machine.
The problem is that when i run my .exe app on this machine i get missing dlls error such as MSVCP140D.DLL, VCRUNTIME140D.dll etc.
I tried to install the vcredist from MSDN on the guest machine and i also tried changing the "runtime library" from the "code generation" module in the project config.
I also followed some other tutorials that i've read on this platform but i can't find nothing that really works.
I even tried to place the missing dlls in the same directory of the .exe file to register them manually, actually it does not work, but this app i'm developing should be redistributable so the user should have just to execute it.

If i try to compile my program with another compiler such as MinGw it works but i wanted to use the vc++ default compiler if possible.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually i'm testing both x64 release and  debug

Comment: What is the value under `Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library` ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast reply! the value is set to "DLL multithread (/MD)" but i also tried (/MDd) and /MT

Comment: For debug build use `/Mtd` and for release use `/Mt`. Run the app on guest machine and let us know for what dll, you get a missing dll error.

Comment: Those are the debug versions of the standard C++ and C runtime libraries.  Note the D at the end of the filename.  They have a lot of asserts in the code and add lots of overhead to malloc/new allocations, helping you to debug your code.  The redist install does not include them and Microsoft does not provide a license to redistribute them.  Not to make your life more difficult, because it doesn't make sense to execute slow and unoptimized C++ code.  You must deploy the Release build of your project.

Comment: I think that updating w10 to the lastest version (1903 is the version that i have on the virtual machine) should fix the problem, but the main fact is that this application that i'm writing should be as native as possible on windows > 8

Comment: `/Mt` should do the trick. You should not require any runtime libraries then. You can check with a tool like cffexplorer to identify what dll's your built executable is linked to.

Comment: This community is every day greater. I solved the problem by adding the /MT in the release section and /Mtd in the debug, thank you guys!

Comment: `/MTd` or `/MDd` are debug versions of the **standard library** and only useful if you want to debug the **standard library**. In most cases, even if you create a debug version of your application, you do not want to debug the **standard library**, thus you probably don't need to use `/MTd` or `/MDd` ever.

Comment: You can't run the debug version on a machine that does not have Visual Studio installed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used MSVCP140.DLL, wihtout the D. the D stands for DEBUG and I don't know if the Debug version version comes with the visual studio redistributable. If you compile in visual studio try to build the Release version, this should work with the DLL´s from the redistributable

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) actually i'm testing both x64 release and debug, forgot to mention in the post ty. It gives me the same DLL errors on x64dbg,x64release,x86release,x86dbg

Comment: The debug CRT does not come in the redistributable.